# Apollo-client query providing data on Network tab but console is null for some fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo, apollo-client

I have using **Apollo-client**. I can see the data on ***network tab*** on chrome, also on edge. But When we console it, some object fields are covert automatically by **NULL**.
Here is my apollo config:

````
      link: ApolloLink.from([errorLink, uploadLink]),
      cache: new InMemoryCache(),
      defaultHttpLink: false,
      connectToDevTools: true,
    });
    
    apollo.defaultOptions = {
      watchQuery: {
        fetchPolicy: "network-only",
        errorPolicy: "ignore",
      },
      query: {
        fetchPolicy: "network-only",
        errorPolicy: "all",
      },
    };
    
    export default apollo;```

[![snap of console][1]][1]
[![snap of network tab][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqKJX.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3m2i.png
````

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I see data in network tab and it looks fine, but response.data from apollo client is null. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: For me the solution was to alter the query. I was doing a query with fragments, but the fragment didn't have an id or similar which means that the InMemoryCache failed. You would think that it could provide some kind of error instead of just returning null. Anyway that was why it failed for me.

Comment: Actually, the problem was in cash management. I changed the fetch policy to `fetchPolicy:"no-cache"` and it's working fine.
`